# Performance difference in json data into BigQuery loading methods

Tags: python, google-bigquery

What is the performance difference between two JSON loading methods into BigQuery:
`load_table_from_file(io.StringIO(json_data)` vs `create_rows_json`

The first one loads the file as a whole and the second one streams the data. Does it mean that the first method will be faster to complete, but binary, and the second one slower, but discretionary?
Any other concerns?
Thanks!

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Comment: Thanks! Didn't notice the tick mark initially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's for two different logics and they have their own limits.

1. Load from file is great if you can have your data placed in files. A file can be up to 5TB in size. This load is free. You can query data immediately after completion.
2. The streaming insert, is great if you have your data in form of events that you can stream to BigQuery. While a streaming insert single request is limited up to 10MB, it can be super parallelized up to 1 Million rows per second, that's a big scale. Streaming rows to BigQuery has it's own cost. You can query data immediately after streaming, but for some `copy` and `export` jobs data can be available later up to 90 minutes.

Comment: Thanks @Pentium10! 
Is there any speed difference?
I'm loading files less than 10MB. And my main question is how long it will take for the job to complete as I need to query the data right after.

Comment: Do whatever is easier for you. I think streaming insert is faster for your purpose. We see around a maximum of 600ms when loading via streaming.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your time!